# sassを使いたいのですが、CSSファイルが自動生成されたりしません。

Tags: css, wordpress, sass

ワードプレスでサイトの制作をしています。

VSCでサイトを作成する場合、sassのファイルを制作すれば、
自動的にcssのファイルが制作されますが、

FileZillaではsassを作っても自動的にcssファイルが出来たりしません。

今までは、VSCでsassファイルを作り、
それで自動生成されたCSSファイルの内容をFileZillaに作ったCSSファイルにコピーしていたのですが、それでは、PHPで作成された画面を見ながらCSSを作ることが出来ません。

一度、VSCでもPHPをできるようにして、さらにMAMPとワードプレスをインストールしてワードプレスをVSCを使ってできるようにしました。
そうすると、今度はsassを制作しても自動的にcssのファイルが制作されなくなってしまいました。
htmlファイルをグーグルで開いてもコードの羅列が表示されるだけです。

どうすれば、PHPで作成された画面を見ながら、SCSSでコーディングができるようになりますでしょうか？

急ぎですので、ほかサイトでも質問します。

Answer (score 0):

プラグインのWP-SCSSをインストールして設定を正しくすることで、
ワードプレスのcssのsass化を行えました。